# Having an issue about my joomla site

Tags: web, joomla, hosting, web-hosting

I was trying to delete some unused database in my web-host but i stupidly deleted the database of my Joomla website database w/out knowing it.

My problem is when i try to go to the site it says:

error:

```
Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Could not connect to MySQL
```

Does anyone know how to recover the deleted database of a Joomla website? Please i need your help guys :(

I have a backup of my joomla directory but i dont have a backup of my dabatase :(

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you have no  backup of your database sql, you cannot recover your site.

Usually, hosts backup sites and databases daily, weekly and monthly.

Contact your hosting company and they can recover your site.